# Is it possible to use the server side certificate of MySQL DB in implementing SSL connections?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have given a mysql user that has SSL capability. DBA said that there should be no changes on application level since it is a user configuration.

While I can use the said user in MySQL Workbench, I can't use it in the Spring Boot application.

Will there be any changes in the connection string when using this SSL-enabled user? Or is it really possible to use the server side certificate?

Connection string is: jdbc:mysql://host:port/schema?autoReconnect=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

Comment: You may have to import the server certificate into your Java truststore. Better still get the DBA to have it signed by a recognized CA.

Comment: this is what i'm requesting from them now. while waiting, i'm still trying to use the same user without injecting the certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DBA is incorrect with the directives they have given. I think it is not possible to do this as every certificate is really needed to implement an SSL connection.